# Instantiate an IQueryable<> from a refelected type

Tags: c#

I have a `ClassName` string. I created a reflected `List` of objects:

```
Type objectType = Type.GetType(ClassName);
var listObjectType = typeof(List<>);
var constructedListObjectType = listObjectType.MakeGenericType(objectType);
object listObject = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedListObjectType);
```

Now I want `listObject` to be `IQueryable<ClassName>` not `List<ClassName>`.

Comment: The simplest option would be to call `Enumerable.AsQueryable((dynamic) listObject)`. But it's not clear what you're going to do after that - are you sure having an `IQueryable` based on a list is actually going to achieve your bigger goal? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: A List is already an  `IEnumerable<T>` and can be used with LINQ. Why do you want to convert it to an `IQueryable<T>`? If there is a valid reason, you could simply call `Queryable.AsQueryable()` on it.

Comment: BTW you *can't* instantiate `IQueryable<T>`. It's an interface. You can use a `List<T>` with LINQ without any modifications. Or you can do what [the source of Queryable.AsQueryable()](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq.Queryable/src/System/Linq/Queryable.cs#L14) does and wrap an `EnumerableQuery<T>` around it. Or simply call `Queryable.AsQueryable()` with the object as a parameter

Comment: The reason for this is to get an IQueryable<> returned value by InvokMember method. But when doing Queryable.AsQueryable() I got System.Reflection.TargetException: 'Object does not match target type.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unclear what you want to do, but you asked for something and you'll get what you asked.

```
string className = "System.String";
Type type = Type.GetType(className);
var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type);

// This is a List<type> but it is easier to handle it through
// its non-generic IEnumerable interface
var list = (IEnumerable)Activator.CreateInstance(listType);

// Note that in truth this will return a IQueryable<type>
IQueryable queryable = Queryable.AsQueryable(list);
```

There are two overloads for `Queryable.AsQueryable`. One requires a `IEnumerable<T>` and returns the corresponding `IQueryable<>`, the other requires a `IEnumerable`, checks that in truth it is a `IEnumerable<T>` and returns a `IQueryable<T>` downcasted to `IQueryable`. I'm using the second one.

Comment: How to use IEnumerable<T> in this case

Comment: @أحمدمحروس Unclear what you are asking. How to use `IEnumerable<T>` *where* exactly.

Comment: I want to get  IQueryable<T> not IQueryable

Comment: @أحمدمحروس It *is* a `IQueryable<T>`. But the variable can't be of type `IQueryable<T>`. So I downcast it to `IQueryable`. I could have used `object`. It would have been the same. Now you have discovered that using generic types with reflection is a pain :-) Use the method suggested by Bob Vale. He incapsulates the generic part of the method in a secondary method `CreateList<T>` and uses reflection to invoke it. In this way you have a method that "knows" of T at compile time.

Comment: I try all solution the problem is when use InvokeMethod it give System.Reflection.TargetException: 'Object does not match target type.' beacause the target type must be  IQueryable<T>

Comment: @أحمدمحروس Update your question with an example... My code works correctly, and returns a `IQueryable<T>` downcasted. Bob Vale too. Note that you can/should put as much code as you can *inside* the `CreateList<>` method of Bob Vale, where you have access to both the empty `List<T>` *and* the `IQueryable<T>`. So you should change it to: `var list = new List<T>(); /* use list here */; var queryable = list.AsQueryable(); /* use iqueryable here */; return queryable;`

Answer (score 1):

This helper method should do what you want.  Inside of CreateList you can do what you like with the strongly typed list.  `GetQuerable` will return the querable cast as an object.

Obviously make sure you have the correct usings so that `AsQuerable()` works

```
public static class Helper
{

    public static object GetQueryable(string type) {
        var method = typeof(Helper).GetMethod(nameof(CreateList));
        return method.MakeGenericMethod(Type.GetType(type)).Invoke(null, new object[0]);
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> CreateList<T>()
    {
        return new List<T>().AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

To Use:

```
var listObject  = Helper.GetQuerable("System.Int32");
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        var listGenericParameter = typeof(ClassName);
        var listObjectType = typeof(List<>);
        var constructedListObjectType = listObjectType.MakeGenericType(listGenericParameter);
        var listInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedListObjectType);
        var asQueryableMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethod(nameof(Queryable.AsQueryable), new[] { typeof(IEnumerable) }) ??
                                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Could not find method AsQueryable() on type {nameof(Queryable)}");

        var listAsQueryable = asQueryableMethod.Invoke(null, new [] { listInstance });
        // method.Invoke('method owner instance', 'method args') 
        // first arg is null because AsQueryable() is extension method = static 
        // => there is no instance "owning" the method (just an owner type)

        (listAsQueryable is IQueryable<ClassName>).Should().BeTrue();
    }

    public class ClassName { }
```

edit: fixed the code to not be missleading, after comments from xonos

Comment: Have you checked the code? In the end you are using reflection to get `Queryable.AsQueryable(IEnumerable)` (the non generic version). You can use it without reflection.

Comment: Yes, I have. I would argue I get the `Queryable.AsQueryable<T>(IEnumerable<T>)` method (see the `constructedEnumerableType` variable which I'm passing in the `typeof(Queryable).GetMethod()`)

Comment: @xanatos Edited my answer to be a test

Comment: Try doing `bool res = asQueryableMethod.IsGenericMethod; // get false`. Then try doing `typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().Where(x => x.Name == "AsQueryable" && x.IsGenericMethod).Single().ToString()` and you'll get `System.Linq.IQueryable``1[TElement] AsQueryable[TElement](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable``1[TElement])`

Comment: @xanatos ah, I see now - you are right! I for some reason match the AsQueryable(IEnumerable), even though I pass IEnumerable<ClassName> as an argument (and dont match the other - generic version, otherwise I would get exc "ambigious match found")

Comment: You can't get a generic method with `GetMethod()`, because the argument is for example `IEnumerable<T>`, where the `T` is "special". You can't look for it b using `IEnumerable<object>`. You need the "special" `T`.

Comment: For example: `MethodInfo asQueryableTElement = (from x in typeof(Queryable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public) 
where x.Name == nameof(Queryable.AsQueryable)
let args = x.GetGenericArguments()
where args.Length == 1 
let pars = x.GetParameters()
where pars.Length == 1 && pars[0].ParameterType == typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(args[0])
select x).Single();`. Then you need to do `var asQueryable = asQueryableTElement.MakeGenericMethod(listGenericParameter)`

Comment: clear, thanks for pointing out! : ) (I wonder what to do with my answer now)